# Sorting a nX3 matrix (Most efficient way)

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist, collections

I am writing code for Mo's algorithm  with update in JAVA , so in this we have to order in ascending order an ArrayList of N X 3 matrix in this way

The ArrayList is of the form

```
Ai,Bi,Ci
```

For example:

```
1,2,3
2,3,4
1,2,1
2,3,5
```

so to sort them , first look for all the Ai, if  there is a clash like in Ai of 1,2,3 and 1,2,1 ,then look for Bi,if there is a clash ,then look for Ci, and sort them accordingly .

```
Sorted array
1,2,1
1,2,3
2,3,4
2,3,5
```

So is there any data structure to sort them without having to write a big long piece of code ?

Those who are asking for my code in comments-->

```
// RIGHT NOW I HAVEN'T MADE AN N X # MATRIX ,WHAT I HAVE DONE IS TAKEN 3 ARRAYLISTS , yes I WILL CHANGE IT INTO A SINGLE ARRAYLIST OF SIZE N X 3
public class MoSAlgorithmUpdates {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    //finding no of distict numbers
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    String str;
    //Taking the Array Now
    str=br.readLine();
    ArrayList<Integer> arr=new ArrayList<Integer>();
    StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(str," ");
    while(st.hasMoreTokens())
    {
        arr.add(Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken()));
    }

    // Total q queries including updates + finding distinct numbers

    int Q;
    str = br.readLine();
    Q = Integer.parseInt(str);
    int[] q1=new int[Q];
    int[] q2=new int[Q];
    int[] q3=new int[Q];
    int[] q4=new int[Q];
    ArrayList<Integer> query1=new ArrayList<Integer>();// RIGHT NOW I HAVEN'T MADE AN N X # MATRIX ,WHAT I HAVE DONE IS TAKEN 3 ARRAYLISTS , yes I WILL CHANGE IT INTO A SINGLE ARRAYLIST OF SIZE N X 3
    ArrayList<Integer> query2=new ArrayList<Integer>();// RIGHT NOW I HAVEN'T MADE AN N X # MATRIX ,WHAT I HAVE DONE IS TAKEN 3 ARRAYLISTS , yes I WILL CHANGE IT INTO A SINGLE ARRAYLIST OF SIZE N X 3
    ArrayList<Integer> query3=new ArrayList<Integer>();// RIGHT NOW I HAVEN'T MADE AN N X # MATRIX ,WHAT I HAVE DONE IS TAKEN 3 ARRAYLISTS , yes I WILL CHANGE IT INTO A SINGLE ARRAYLIST OF SIZE N X 3
    ArrayList<Integer> update1=new ArrayList<Integer>();
    ArrayList<Integer> update2=new ArrayList<Integer>();
    ArrayList<Integer> update3=new ArrayList<Integer>();
    //int[] update1=new int[Q];
    int noofupdates=0;
    //noofupdates=time

    for(int i2=0;i2<Q;i2++)
    {
        str=br.readLine();
        StringTokenizer st2 = new StringTokenizer(str," ");

        q1[i2]=Integer.parseInt(st2.nextToken());

        q2[i2]=Integer.parseInt(st2.nextToken());
        q3[i2]=Integer.parseInt(st2.nextToken());

        if(q1[i2]==1)
        {
            query1.add(q2[i2]);
            query2.add(q3[i2]);
            query3.add(noofupdates);
        }
        else
        {
            update1.add(q2[i2]);
            update2.add(q3[i2]);
            noofupdates++;
        }
    }
  }
}
```

**LAST QUERY-->**

IN Mo's Algorithm with updates, we arrange the ArrayList by

```
int sqrt = Math.sqrt(N) // N is the length of ArrayList containing all the 
                        // numbers from which range queries have to be told
```

now sort the . numbers as

Now let's say L,R,time are for eg

```
1,3,3
2,3,4
2,1,1
2,3,5
```

So sorting them by L,R,time returns result as

```
Sorted array
1,3,3
2,1,1
2,3,4
2,3,5
```

Now sorting them by  has to be done ,how can be that done ? the final output has to  be like without square root that is the values L,R,time should not change but sorting has to be done with  . How to achieve that -- ?

The final output may look like this depending on the value of N

```
2,1,1
1,3,3 //Very Imp see this it is sorted
2,3,4
2,3,5
```

Comment: Presumably you could concatenate the columns into a single list and sort that via existing methods?

Comment: Is your data structure an _ArrayList_ or an _array_?  Please show us some relevant code.

Comment: ArrayList is my data structure , so i want to use Any built in methods from Collections

Comment: show us your code please

Comment: @ patrick-hainge  letz say i have 1,12,3 and i have 11,2,3 then how will i sort them if i combine them they both are the same that is 1123  ,how will i figure out which number is which ?

Comment: I added full **working** code in my answer. Check please.

Answer (score 1):

Radix sort
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_sort

You can use default sort method of collections

```
Collections.sort(yourArrayN2, comparator);
```

You should define comparator which compares both arrays starting from first elements (we assume that these arrays / lists have the same size; otherwise you will modify the comparator).

Comparator:

```
    public class ListComparator implements Comparator<List<Integer>> {

        @Override
        public int compare(List<Integer> list1, List<Integer> list2) {
            if (list1 == null || list2 == null || list1 == list2) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException();
            }

            int size = list1.size();
            if (size != list2.size()) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException();
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                int delta = list1.get(i) - list2.get(i);
                if (delta != 0) {
                    return delta;
                }
            }

            return 0;
        }
    }
```

And its usage

```
public class App {

    public void execute() {
        List<List<Integer>> list2D = make2DList();
        printList2D(list2D);
        System.out.println("\n");
        Collections.sort(list2D, new ListComparator());
        printList2D(list2D);
    }

    //This is where you create your 2D list. It can be read from file, etc.
    private List<List<Integer>> make2DList() {
        List<List<Integer>> res = new ArrayList<>(3);
        res.add(makeList(1,2,3));
        res.add(makeList(2,3,4));
        res.add(makeList(1,2,1));
        res.add(makeList(2,3,5));
        return res;
    }

    private List<Integer> makeList(Integer ... numbers) {
        List<Integer> res = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Integer i : numbers) {
            res.add(i);
        }
        return res;
    }

    private void printList2D(List<List<Integer>> list2D) {
        for (List<Integer> list : list2D) {
            printList(list);
        }
    }

    private void printList(List<Integer> list) {
        int size = list.size();
        int lastIndex = size - 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < lastIndex; i++) {
            System.out.print(list.get(i) + ", ");
        }
        System.out.print(list.get(lastIndex) + "\n");
    }
}
```

It prints

```
1, 2, 3
2, 3, 4
1, 2, 1
2, 3, 5


1, 2, 1
1, 2, 3
2, 3, 4
2, 3, 5
```

Comment: U have used a single ArrayList or 3 ArrayLists ?I am cool with any but i need to know what u have used

Comment: @ErrorrrDetector     **yourArrayN2** is 2D (2 dimention) list containing lists. **list1**,**list2** are 1D list containing numbers

Comment: Can u explain to me just this portion what u have done in this ?                        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                int delta = list1.get(i) - list2.get(i);
                
                if (delta != 0) {
                    return delta;
                }
            }                                             //  , if u return 0 what happens with the compartor  /does it swap or what it does when 0 is returned ?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html  In other words, A < B means Comparator.compare(A, B) < 0. A == B means   Comparator.compare(A, B)  = 0.  Instead of writing if (list1[i] - list2[i] > 0) ... else if (list1[i] - list2[i] > 0) ... else. I just shortened this logic: (list1[i] - list2[i]) is repeated twice.

Comment: **Be careful**. The solution above solves this task for Numbers (in our case, Integers). For other objects, instead of **int delta = list1.get(i) - list2.get(i);** use **int delta = list1.get(i) . compareTo ( list2.get(i) );**